# Is it possible to integrate a custom skill with alexa voice service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

i have a raspberry pi hardware set up  and I have integrated this device with alexa-voice-service using python client running as per the amazon developer document. Now I would like to know whether is it possible to integrate custom skill build using lambda function with this alexa voice service as we do with the alexa skills kit.

In brief is it possible to use the credentials of the registered device with Alexa voice service in the lambda function?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the credentials of one with the other. Amazon partitions them quite strictly.

If you want to create a skill that works with that one device only, you can do this. Create your skill as normal, but don't try to certify it. If the user of your device is logged in with the same ID as the developer account that submitted the skill, then that skill should be accessible to it. If you use a different ID, you can add that ID as another develop skill on that account. Then make sure "enabled" is selected on the skill's testing tab for the new user.

Comment: As per your feedback I guess I can't use lambda function for alexa voice service, I can use lambda function for only alexa skill kit. right ? Is that what you meant?

Comment: You can't use a Lambda function for an AVS device. But you state you are already using python on a Pi for your client. That's fine.

You can use Lambda for a custom skill. This is a completely separate thing. They cannot share credentials or anything explicitly. You cannot "integrate" them, per se, as they are two completely separate things.

But, my suggestion was that if you don't make the skill side public, it is only available to the developer who created it. If the AVS side is logged in as them, then only they will see it.